# Square API Create Payment Method not working

Tags: reactjs, django-rest-framework, square

I am using Square for payment transactions in my project. My backend is in Django while the front-end is in react.

```
client = Client(
            access_token=square_access_token,
            environment='sandbox', # Change to production for real-time use
        )
```

**When using Sandbox**

I use these dummy card credentials to make payments
Visa    4111 1111 1111 1111 111
But the response i get on payment completion is

**Response**

```
 "payment": {
      "id": "1KK5WB7U0wUTvfD6timig8BrNkcZY",
      "created_at": "2023-07-12T11:46:27.987Z",
      "updated_at": "2023-07-12T11:46:28.179Z",
      "amount_money": {
        "amount": 100,
        "currency": "USD"
      },
      "status": "COMPLETED",
      "delay_duration": "PT168H",
      "source_type": "CARD",
      "card_details": {
        "status": "CAPTURED",
        "card": {
          "card_brand": "VISA",
          "last_4": "5858",
          "exp_month": 7,
          "exp_year": 2025,
          "fingerprint": "sq-1-PKjMTo-XRrc6VvfaMvpB1ZjsdGsokrBQ6ug_uQYuuWE324Cs72DY1LN8XmFbzlijMA",
          "card_type": "CREDIT",
          "prepaid_type": "NOT_PREPAID",
          "bin": "453275"
        },
        "entry_method": "KEYED",
        "cvv_status": "CVV_ACCEPTED",
        "avs_status": "AVS_ACCEPTED",
        "statement_description": "SQ *DEFAULT TEST ACCOUNT",
        "card_payment_timeline": {
          "authorized_at": "2023-07-12T11:46:28.100Z",
          "captured_at": "2023-07-12T11:46:28.180Z"
        }
      },
      "location_id": "LHVKEM4ZHDVTQ",
      "order_id": "eYRROI4TPhqZp1Jo7OPIMY6dld4F",
      "total_money": {
        "amount": 100,
        "currency": "USD"
      },
      "approved_money": {
        "amount": 100,
        "currency": "USD"
      },
      "receipt_number": "1KK5",
      "receipt_url": "https://squareupsandbox.com/receipt/preview/1KK5WB7U0wUTvfD6timig8BrNkcZY",
      "delay_action": "CANCEL",
      "delayed_until": "2023-07-19T11:46:27.987Z",
      "application_details": {
        "square_product": "ECOMMERCE_API",
        "application_id": "sandbox-sq0idb-0emHpEyQ_pLCt9NTUzBPGQ"
      },
      "version_token": "CvoStjzzLtJWmoFfLFoO9pFcrCMTQaiOkp4S3Huv3bs6o"
    }
  }
}
```

If you look at last_4 attribute, it always returns 5858 whereas i think it should have returned the last four 1111 of entered card number. Also the application_id and location_id returned in response is also different from my credentials but that may be due to cache, it may be getting old cached credentials.

**My django views.py code:**

```
def post(self, request):
  user_id = request.data['UserId']
  source_id = request.data['source_id']
  create_payment_response = client.payments.create_payment(
                  body={
                      "source_id": source_id,
                      "idempotency_key": idempotency_key,
                      "amount_money": {
                          "amount": int(total_cost)*100,  # $1.00 charge
                          "currency": 'USD',
                      },
                  }
              )
  if create_payment_response.is_success():
                  """ Do some processing """
                  return Response({"message": "Payment Successful", "data": create_payment_response.body},
                                  status=status.HTTP_200_OK)
  elif create_payment_response.is_error():
      return Response(create_payment_response.errors)
```

**My React Code:**

```
<PaymentForm
        applicationId="app_id"
        locationId='loc_id'
        cardTokenizeResponseReceived={async (tokenn, verifiedBuyer) => {
          console.log("payment token ",tokenn.token);
          const response = await fetch( "base_url/api/payment/checkout/",{
            method:"POST",
            headers:{
              'Content-Type': 'application/json',
              "Authorization": `Bearer ${token}`,
            },
            body:JSON.stringify({
              UserId:userId,
              source_id:"cnon:card-nonce-ok"
            })
          })
          console.log(JSON.stringify(await response.clone().json(),null,2))
          const jsonObject = JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(await response.json(),null,2));
          if(jsonObject){
            // setOpen(true)
            handleOpen()
            setModelData(jsonObject)
              if(jsonObject.message== "Payment Successful"){
                  fetchData({})
                }
            // handleClose()
          }
        }}
      >
          <CreditCard
          style={{
            "input": {
              fontSize: '14px'
            },
          }} />
</PaymentForm>
```

**When using production**
Just like that when i shift to production for testing if cards are being charged or not.
I do all the necessary steps like changing the credentials from sandbox to production credentials (application_id, access_token, location_id) and also environment to production. From my react side code i also change source_id

source_id:tokenn.token

But i get below error

**ERROR**

```
[
  {
    "code": "NOT_FOUND",
    "detail": "Card nonce not found",
    "category": "INVALID_REQUEST_ERROR"
  }
]
```

I don't know what is the issue and I am stuck at this point.

I tried the approach described in the API documentary and also searched the error. What i found is that in response on payment successful the application id and location id is different, it is of some other application which i used at start of this project for testing but it still returns that in response.